# I want to find the critical points and their nature of this multivariate function $3x^3 +9x^2 -72x+2y^3-12y^2-126y+19$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

$3x^3 +9x^2 -72x+2y^3-12y^2-126y+19$

I want to find critical points and their nature of this equation.
When I equated $f_x$ and $f_y$ to 0, I m getting $x=2,x=-4$ for $f_x=0$ and $y=-3,y=7$ for $f_y=0$.

now, when I substitute x=2 in f(x,y) I m getting $2y^3-12y^2-126y=65$
which is a cubic equation. I am stuck here and don't know how to solve this...can somebody help?

https://www.geekandnerd.org/criticalsaddle-point-calculator-for-fxy/ - it shows four critical points by combining above ones.can we always do this?whats the logic behind doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

> https://www.geekandnerd.org/criticalsaddle-point-calculator-for-fxy/ - it shows four critical points by combining above ones.can we always do this?whats the logic behind doing the same?

The logic is that critical points are the points satisfying $f_x = 0$ **and** $f_y=0$, it is a system of two equations. Your calculations show that $x=2$ and $x=-4$ satisfy the first equation and $y=-3$ and $y=7$ satisfy the second, so there are four points which satisfy **both equations** (*simulnateously*):
$$\left(2,-3\right) \;,\; \left(2,7\right)\;,\; \left(-4,-3\right)\;,\; \left(-4,7\right)$$
Now you still need to check the nature of these critical points, e.g. with the second derivative test. Can you take it from there?

---

Addition after comment. The system you need to solve is:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
f_x = 0 \\
f_y = 0
\end{array}\right. \iff 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
9 (x - 2) (x + 4) = 0 \\
6 (y - 7) (y + 3) = 0
\end{array}\right.$$
A solution to this system of two equations is not *an $x$-value* (or *a $y$-value*) but a **pair** $(x,y)$ satisfying **both** equations. Does that help?

Comment: But wait – how can the cubic equation $2y^3-12y^2-126y=65$ have just 2 solutions, and how can $y=-3$ and $y=7$ be solutions?

Comment: Gerry, that equation we get after substituing x=2 in f(x,y). y=-3 and y=7 are the solution we get when we equate partial derivetive of y to 0

Comment: @GerryMyerson You never arrive at the cubic, the solutions follow from the system $\left\{f_x=0,f_y=0\right\}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added a bit too my answer.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I can take it forward!

Comment: @KashmiraZambad Oh, from the comments I figured Gerry was the OP! :-) Anyway, you're welcome!